# Second call to reqContractDetails in TWS API doesn't send any notification and hangs

Tags: c#, interactive-brokers, tws

Trying to create kind of market scanner. Code below is supposed to return chain of option contracts. Call to TWS API is an async method that returns some data only if I get ContractEnd or Error response from TWS. On the first call to reqContractDetails() it works as expected, I get list of contracts, receive message "ContractEnd", and exit from the method.

**Obstacle**

In some reason, on the second call to reqContractDetails() I don't get any notification from TWS. I have to stop and restart my application, initiating new connection to the server to make it working again.

**Update**

After refactoring my code I'm getting an error on a second call that says "Unable to read beyond the end of the stream". Call stack looks this way.

```
IBLibrary.dll!IBLibrary.OptionService.GetOptionsChain.AnonymousMethod__3(IBLibrary.Messages.ErrorMessage data) Line 64
IBLibrary.dll!IBLibrary.Classes.Client.error(string str) Line 42
CSharpAPI.dll!IBApi.EReader.putMessageToQueue() Line 94
CSharpAPI.dll!IBApi.EReader.Start.AnonymousMethod__9_0() Line 48
```

**My implementation of the wrapper in C#**

```
public class BaseService : IDisposable
{
  protected Client Sender { get; set; }
  protected EReader Receiver { get; set; }

  public BaseService()
  {
    Sender = new Client();
    Sender.Socket.eConnect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0);
    Receiver = new EReader(Sender.Socket, Sender.Signal);
    Receiver.Start();

    var process = new Thread(() =>
    {
      while (Sender.Socket.IsConnected())
      {
        Sender.Signal.waitForSignal();
        Receiver.processMsgs();
      }
    })
    {
      IsBackground = true
    };

    process.Start();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Sender.Socket.eDisconnect();
  }
}

public class OptionService : BaseService
{
  public Task<List<OptionModel>> GetOptionsChain(OptionModel query)
  {
    if (query == null)
    {
      query = new OptionModel();
    }

    var process = Task.Run(() =>
    {
      var done = false;
      var id = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Next();

      var contract = new Contract
      {
        Symbol = query.Symbol,
        SecType = "OPT",
        Exchange = "SMART",
        Currency = "USD",
        LastTradeDateOrContractMonth = query.Expiration
      };

      var contracts = new List<OptionModel>();

      Action<ErrorMessage> errorMessage = null;
      Action<ContractDetailsMessage> contractMessage = null;
      Action<ContractDetailsEndMessage> contractMessageEnd = null;

      contractMessage = (ContractDetailsMessage data) =>
      {
        contracts.Add(new OptionModel
        {
          Symbol = data.ContractDetails.Contract.Symbol,
          Right = data.ContractDetails.Contract.Right,
          Strike = data.ContractDetails.Contract.Strike,
          Expiration = data.ContractDetails.RealExpirationDate
        });
      };

      // I receive this message at first, but not the second time

      contractMessageEnd = (ContractDetailsEndMessage data) =>
      {
        done = true;
      };

      errorMessage = (ErrorMessage data) =>
      {
        var notifications = new List<int>
        {
          (int) ErrorCode.MarketDataFarmConnectionIsOK,
          (int) ErrorCode.HmdsDataFarmConnectionIsOK
        };

        if (notifications.Contains(data.ErrorCode) == false)
        {
          done = true;
        }
      };

      Sender.ErrorEvent += errorMessage;
      Sender.ContractDetailsEvent += contractMessage;
      Sender.ContractDetailsEndEvent += contractMessageEnd;
      Sender.Socket.reqContractDetails(id, contract);

      // Execute method until we get all contracts
      // The econd call to reqContractDetails doesn't return 
      // any notification, so obviously this line hangs forever

      while (done == false);

      Sender.ErrorEvent -= errorMessage;
      Sender.ContractDetailsEvent -= contractMessage;
      Sender.ContractDetailsEndEvent -= contractMessageEnd;

      return contracts;
    });

    return process;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as nobody has the answer, even IB itself, the only solution that I see is, to convert my API controller to a synchronous controller and close socket connection to IB server after every request.

**Old version.**

```
public class ServiceOptionsController : BaseServiceController
{
  OptionService Service = new OptionService();

  [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
  public async Task<List<OptionModel>> Options([FromBody] dynamic data)
  {
    var selectors = data.ToObject<QueryModel>();

    var optionModel = new OptionModel
    {
      Symbol = "MSFT",
      Expiration = "201806"
    };

    var processes = new List<Task<List<OptionModel>>>
    {
      Service.GetOptionsChain(optionModel)
    };

    return (await Task.WhenAll(processes)).SelectMany(o => o).ToList();
  }
}
```

**Working version.**

```
public class ServiceOptionsController : BaseServiceController
{
  [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
  public List<OptionModel> Options([FromBody] dynamic data)
  {
    var selectors = data.ToObject<QueryModel>();

    var optionModel = new OptionModel
    {
      Symbol = "MSFT",
      Expiration = "201806"
    };

    var optionService = new OptionService();

    var processes = new List<Task<List<OptionModel>>>
    {
      optionService.GetOptionsChain(optionModel)
    };

    var items = Task.WhenAll(processes).Result.SelectMany(o => o).ToList();

    optionService.Dispose(); // Ridiculous fix for ridiculous API

    return items;
  }
}
```